# Loading External JavaScript file after view page is loaded in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div ng-app>
```

```
<form ng-submit="addTodo()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="todoText"  size="30"
         placeholder="add new todo here" id="inputtext">
  <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">

</form>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/process1/Process1Controller.js"></script>
```

I want to load specified js file after html load since id of input textbox is used in js .

i have seen different thread and done many experiments for this like

$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){

}) 
but issue not resolved

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Angular-Controller do start after the DOM is ready. So it is irrelevant when the script is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack, and not likely the proper way to do things, but try using ng-if to dynamically populate the items on the page:

//HTML

```
<script ng-init='myVariable = true' ng-if='myVariable' type="text/javascript" src="myJsToLoad.js"></script>
```

again, this is not the proper way to do things in angular, but it should work

Answer (score 0):

As per my suggestion,

put the entire js code in a function, like below:

```
function loadmyjs(){
    // put your entire related js code here...
}
```

And inside the current controller, call that js method like, When your id is created....

```
loadmyjs();
```